# Server is returning a 303 unless running an insecure version of Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, playframework

We are writing a web application using the Play framework hosted on Heroku. We wrote a rest API and are accessing it from Chrome.  When we use an insecure version of Chrome we get no errors but when we try and use Chrome with the security settings we are getting a 303 from the server with a blank console in Chrome.  The server logs say that the cookie isn't being sent with the request. Our headers are being set as:

```
{
   response().setHeader("access-control-allow-origin", "*");<br>
   response().setHeader("access-control-allow-methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");<br>
   response().setHeader("access-control-allow-headers", "AUTHORIZATION");   <br>
 }
```

I think we have some Cross Domain problem but I am not sure how to fix it. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  On the AJAX call from the application we needed to add:

xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}

and we needed to remove:

response().setHeader("access-control-allow-origin", "*");

from the server response and only specifically allow the domains we were allowing (localhost).